# What is setting Content-Encoding to "none" in my HTTP response header?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have WordPress on a LAMP stack. Somehow "Content-Encoding" is being returned with a value of "none" in the HTTP response header.

1. I can't locate any offending code in WordPress core, the theme, or any plugins
2. I don't see any such directive in .htaccess
3. I'm not aware of any Apache config that would result in a value of "none"

Thoughts? Wisdom? Whiskey?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does Tomcat come into play?  And, what problem is this header causing you?  Are you by chance serving requests to an HTTP/1.0 client?  Perhaps gzipped responses are just not enabled.

Comment: Wordpress has NOTHING to do with tomcat.

Comment: It's true that WordPress has nothing to do with Tomcat. It's also true that the 'A' in the 'LAMP' reference is for Apache Tomcat, and that Tomcat is one of the stack components capable of altering the response header in question.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you have gzip compression disabled in PHP. This could set the Content-Encoding header.

[zlib.output_compression](http://php.net/zlib.output_compression)

Comment: Thanks. I don't believe it ever results in a value of "none", though.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement seems to be false.

```
if (ini_get('output_buffering') && !isset($agent['bot']))
{ 
    ob_end_clean(); 
    header('Content-Encoding: none');
    $do_gzip_compress = false;
}

if (GZIPSUPPORT && !ini_get('zlib.output_compression') && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING']) && preg_match('/gzip/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'])) 
{
    if (version_compare(PHPVERS, '5.0.0', '>=')) 
    {   # PHP 4.2.x seems to give memleak
        ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
    } 
    else 
    {
        $do_gzip_compress = true;
        ob_start();
        ob_implicit_flush(0);
        header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
    }
} 
else 
{
    ob_start();
    ob_implicit_flush(0);
}
```

Comment: none is perfectly valid if you are not using any header compression at all